# Laravel Model Relationship between Students and Courses

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model *Student* and *Course*.
Here's what I am trying to get from those models,

Every student is enrolled to one course and the way I save it to the database is like below,

```
Student Info..., course_id... <- which is basically taken from the Courses table
```

I want to retrieve the ***Course name*** since I already have the *course_id* stored in the Students table.

I designed the model like:

```
//Course Model
class Course extends Model
{    
    public function student(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
    }
}

//Student Model
class Student extends Model
{    
    public function course(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Course');
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to or what to do next, I am really new to Eloquent approach. 
Need help.

I tried to retrieve the Course name using the code below :

```
$students = Student::all(); 

@foreach($students as $student)
   $student->course->name  
....
```

but I think it is wrong, I'm only getting an error about unknown column

Comment: What is the column name of course for `name` ?

Comment: it's `name` as well

Comment: What is your migration for foreign keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using belongsToMany for student relation in Course.php model,

Use [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) function like:

//Course Model

```
class Course extends Model
{    
    public function student(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
    }
}
```

//Student Model

Since, student belongs to course, you should use **belongsTo** instead of *hasOne*

```
class Student extends Model
{    
    public function course(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
    }
}
```

In order to optimize the query for retrieving all related courses, you can use with [Eagar Loading relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like:

```
$students = Student::with('course')->all(); 

@foreach($students as $student)
//If incase there are no course related to the student
   $student->course->name ?? null   
....
```

Comment: let me check and do the adjustments

Answer (score 2):

Previous Code :

```
//Course Model
class Course extends Model
{    
   public function student(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
   } 
}

//Student Model
class Student extends Model
{    
   public function course(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Course');
   }
}
```

Replace with :

```
//Course Model
 class Course extends Model
 {    
    public function students(){
       return $this->hasMany(Student::class); // '\App\Student' also ok
    } 
 }

 //Student Model 
 class Student extends Model
 {    
    public function course(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }
  }
```

Why belongsTo at Student Model ?

Inside : When a table primary key assign in another table as foreign key then you should add belongsTo this assigning table.
Here Courses table primary id assigned as foreign key at Students table